# Use '.remove()' in a loop to remove the node, why all the nodes won't be removed

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head><body>

<style>
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
</style>

<script>
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let div1 = document.createElement('div');
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  let div3 = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = "alert alert-success";
  div1.className = "alert alert-success";
  div2.className = "alert alert-success";
  div3.className = "alert alert-success";
  
  div.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div1.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!1</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div2.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!2</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div3.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!3</strong> You've read an important message.";
  
  document.body.append(div);
  document.body.append(div1);
  document.body.append(div2);
  document.body.append(div3);
  
  let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(let x of divs){
    x.remove();  
  }
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am recently learning the JS, here is a problem I met.
I think all the 'div' will be removed, 
but div1 and div3 are still there....
I don't know why, please help
And also explain why this happens?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does someone knows why the w3 spec defined the iterator in that way? It seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns not array but a live HTML collection.
 The collection itself is mutated by the `remove()` method, which causes unexpected behavior.

The solution: you need to cast it to array before looping

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
let div1 = document.createElement('div');
let div2 = document.createElement('div');
let div3 = document.createElement('div');

div.className = "alert alert-success";
div1.className = "alert alert-success";
div2.className = "alert alert-success";
div3.className = "alert alert-success";

div.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!</strong> You've read an important message.";
div1.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!1</strong> You've read an important message.";
div2.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!2</strong> You've read an important message.";
div3.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!3</strong> You've read an important message.";

document.body.append(div);
document.body.append(div1);
document.body.append(div2);
document.body.append(div3);

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(let x of Array.from(divs)) {
  console.log(x.innerHTML);
  x.remove();
}
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Because it returns a "live" collection. The collection is mutated by the `.remove()`. Which is what cases the "funny" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the array of all the `divs` you got by tag name using the length of the divs array variable you created.

```js
 let div = document.createElement('div');
  let div1 = document.createElement('div');
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  let div3 = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = "alert alert-success";
  div1.className = "alert alert-success";
  div2.className = "alert alert-success";
  div3.className = "alert alert-success";
  
  div.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div1.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!1</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div2.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!2</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div3.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!3</strong> You've read an important message.";
  
  document.body.append(div);
  document.body.append(div1);
  document.body.append(div2);
  document.body.append(div3);
  
  let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), x;
  for (x = divs.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    divs[x].parentNode.removeChild(divs[x]);
}
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head><body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns NodeList, not array. NodeList might be iterable object but doesn't have to. To iterate using `for ... of` construction it is safer to convert NodeList to array using:

- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- spread operator: `for (let x of [...divs]) { ... }`

```js
 let div = document.createElement('div');
  let div1 = document.createElement('div');
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  let div3 = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = "alert alert-success";
  div1.className = "alert alert-success";
  div2.className = "alert alert-success";
  div3.className = "alert alert-success";
  
  div.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div1.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!1</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div2.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!2</strong> You've read an important message.";
  div3.innerHTML = "<strong>Hi there!3</strong> You've read an important message.";
  
  document.body.append(div);
  document.body.append(div1);
  document.body.append(div2);
  document.body.append(div3);
  
  let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(let x of [...divs]){
    console.log(x.innerHTML);
    x.remove();  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<style>
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```